# MySQL multiplication in select depending on value of column

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I would like to do a select and get a sum, but the multiplication should depend on the value of one of the columns. So this is the regular statement:

```
SELECT col1*col2 AS sum
```

But `if col2 < 0`, col2 should take 0 as value, so something like: `SELECT col1*(col2 < 0 ? 0 : col2) AS sum`

Can I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything multiplied by 0 is 0, so it's a little simpler than your requested logic:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COL2 > 0 THEN COL1 * COL2 ELSE 0 END AS `sum`...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that kind of manipulation and did not know where to look in the manual!

Comment: Link not found error

Comment: @Dgloria: today the link should be: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

In a very compact and elegant solution

```
SELECT IF(col2>0,col1*col2,0) as SUM;
```