# How to use IF() [Control Flow Function] case in the Select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement

I need to make two columns from single column `price` depending upon if it is `used`/`secondhand` or new. Old is indicated by `used` somewhere in `format` column. One being 'price ex tax' other is the `price` with tax. I hope the following code (with no error but malfunction in accordance to my requirement) explains it better.

> case  when format ='%used%' or format='%secondhand%' then CAST(price AS
>   UNSIGNED INTEGER) else CAST(price AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)*0.8  end as
>   'Pris ex Tax',
>   CAST(price AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) as Price

Here basically I need to show a column with price*0.8 for new products and just `price` for used products. 
`format` in the data base contains information for used articles as `used`/`secondhand` but nothing for new.

I followed [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) 
as well as some of the related questions in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907238/mysql-multiplication-in-select-depending-on-value-of-column) 
but not enough for me to understand. 
I tried to put the output here but found it difficult to do that. I will do it if you think will be require to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[This is a great link that teaches Inline IF and CASE statement in MySQL.](http://timmurphy.org/2009/08/13/inline-if-and-case-statements-in-mysql/)**

code snippet:

`IF Statement`

```
SELECT IF(score > 100, 100, score) AS score
FROM exam_results
```

`CASE Statement`

```
SELECT CASE num_heads
WHEN 0 THEN 'Zombie'
WHEN 1 THEN 'Human'
ELSE 'Alien'
END AS race
FROM user
```

Comment: John Woo       Thank you for your quick response, I can understand this code, but while using `if` to compare the `string`, I am confused. Would there be some help considering String comparison which is in the middle of other string as in my code in the question?

Comment: @tough can try this snippet `CASE WHEN format LIKE '%used%' OR format LIKE '%secondhand%'` use **LIKE** instead of `=` (*equal sign*)

Comment: @tough also note that when casting to integer, it should only be `signed` or `unsigned` ex **CAST(price AS UNSIGNED)**